# No reply from my thesis adviser

Tags: thesis

I am currently doing my master thesis on Greenhouse gas emission from solid waste management. I already finished my data collection and now analysing them. But some of the results are not as I expected. So I find the different ways and proposed to my adviser. But my adviser doesn't give any comments about that. And that part is not very important part of my thesis. It is just a small one that I can even leave it if it is on my own. Is that possible to cut some part of my thesis? I have been stucking in this stage about three months. At first, I thought I could publish my thesis and I am hopeless now. And publication also takes time. Please suggest me if there is anything that can help me to move from this stage. Your kind suggestions will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more about what you mean by "my advisor doesn't give any comments"? How did you try to contact your advisor? Email? Phone? In person? And how many times? Depending on the circumstance it could be that your question simply slipped through their mind.

Comment: You shouldn't stay stuck 3 months especially on something which is not a very important part of your work. Why don't you proceed with the solution you proposed in the meantime?

Comment: My entire master's thesis wound up being "these results aren't what I expected, here's some possible reasons why, here's some things for further research." My advisor said that negative results are just as useful as positive ones -- given the number of citations I'd say he's right.

Answer (score 2):

Formulate a version of your thesis without the problematic results. Write it up, at least as an outline, but probably more completely. Analyze it.

But also consider the fact that the results that aren't as expected might invalidate some expectations and lead to a different result. If that is the case, it may be that the "odd" results are pointing you to something important. If so, write that up, instead. Analyze that version.

Then give either or both versions a good look and see how it appears to you. Do you have any results of significance that will carry you to your degree? The next step is to show this work to your advisor and get whatever feedback you can from them. Point out that you have dropped one aspect or changed the focus, but that it holds together, assuming you judge that to be true.

Then take whatever advice you get from the advisor. I suspect you will be told it is fine to proceed, but if not, work out a plan for completion with the advisor.

In general, "not as expected" is a research opportunity, not a setback, but you can probably be successful on one of the two paths.